# java edit function issues on stock in

Tags: java, sql

I am quite new to this so I really appreciate some advice. I've been trying to figure out my problem with this edit function on stock in management for hours and still couldn't find what I did wrong.

```
try{
        int index = jTable1.getSelectedRow();
        String id = jTable1.getValueAt(index, 0).toString();
        String code = txtCode.getText();
```

Amount before edit and to be edited

```
        int oldQty = Integer.parseInt(jTable1.getValueAt(index, 3).toString());
        int newQty = Integer.parseInt(txtQty.getText());
        int diff = newQty - oldQty;
```

looking for code before edit

```
        Connection c = Db.getConnection();
        String oldCode = jTable1.getValueAt(index, 1).toString();
        String sql = "SELECT id FROM tb_product WHERE code=" + oldCode;
        ResultSet rs = c.createStatement().executeQuery(sql);

        rs.next();
        int oldProductId = rs.getInt("id");
```

looking for product

```
        sql = "SELECT id FROM tb_product WHERE code=" + code;
        rs = c.createStatement().executeQuery(sql);
```

update inventory

```
        if (rs.next()) {
            int productId = rs.getInt("id");

            sql = ""
                    + "UPDATE tb_import SET"
                    + "product_id=?, import_qty=?"
                    + "WHERE id=?";

            PreparedStatement pre = c.prepareStatement(sql);

            pre.setInt(1, productId);
            pre.setString(2, txtQty.getText());
            pre.setString(3, id);
            pre.executeUpdate();

            if (oldProductId == productId) {
```

update existing inventory with new value

```
                sql = "UPDATE tb_product SET qty = qty + ? WHERE id=?";

                pre = c.prepareStatement(sql);
                pre.setInt(1, diff);
                pre.setInt(2, productId);
                pre.executeUpdate();

            } else {

                sql = "UPDATE tb_product SET qty = qty - ? WHERE id = ?";

                pre = c.prepareStatement(sql);
                pre.setInt(1, oldQty);
                pre.setInt(2, oldProductId);
                pre.executeUpdate();

                sql = "UPDATE tb_product SET qty = qty + ? WHERE id=?";

                pre = c.prepareStatement(sql);
                pre.setInt(1, newQty);
                pre.setInt(2, productId);
                pre.executeUpdate();
          }
            this.formInternalFrameOpened(null);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }`enter code here`
}
```

Comment: Your SQL queries are rife with errors, because you are concatenating raw strings, and not escaping strings properly.  Look into using prepared statements and then come back here if you still have problems.

Comment: *"still couldn't find what I did wrong"* - Start with why you *think* you've done something wrong.  What actual indication of a problem do you have?  What debugging have you done to find or in any way gather information about that problem?  What exactly have you been *doing* "for hours"?